# Running Android emulator from Jenkins to run Junit test with Robotium

Tags: java, android, testing, android-emulator, jenkins

How can I run Android emulator from Jenkins to run my tests?
When I write in Execiute Windows bath comand, command to run emulator:

> emulator -avd Tester

and run my tests I have this errors:

> ..>emulator -avd Tester  'emulator' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> ..>exit 9009  Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build
>   as failure

I set path for Android_SDK, java in Windows path and it works from cmd.
What should I do to run emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can automate the process with the [Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks, I found this options to create and run emulator, but I have a problem with: "[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to run AVD creation command" I'm running emulator on Jenkins master.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find where the file "emulator.exe" is located, and then run the command in that location. For example, the most probably is that it is located in C:...android-sdk\tools

so, go to the command promt, type cd C:\android-sdk\tools. Then type the command, and it will work just fine. I hope this is the answer even though it´s late. So, accept the answer.